# Hook on arguments in argparse python

Tags: python, inheritance, runtime, argparse

I am interested in hook extra arguments parsed using argparse in one class to another method in another class which already has few arguments parsed using argparse module.

```
Project 1
def x():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--abc')

Project 2
def y():
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     parser.add_argument('--temp1')
     parser.add_argument('--temp2')
```

When I run x(), I want to add the "--abc" argument to the list of argument y() has which is "temp1", "temp2" at runtime. Is inheritance the best way to go and defining the constructors accordingly ? Could someone provide some sample code snippet ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`argparse` implements a `parents` feature that lets you add the arguments of one parser to another.  Check the documentation.  Or to adapt your case:

```
parser_x = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser_x.add_argument('--abc')
parser_y = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[parser_x])
parser_y.add_argument('--temp1')
parser_y.add_argument('--temp2')
parser_y.print_help()
```

prints:

```
usage: ipython [-h] [--abc ABC] [--temp1 TEMP1] [--temp2 TEMP2]    
optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --abc ABC
  --temp1 TEMP1
  --temp2 TEMP2
```

The `add_help=False` is needed to avoid a conflict between the `-h` that `parser_x` would normally add with the one that `parser_y` gets.

Another way is to let `x` add its argument to a predefined parser:

```
def x(parser=None):
    if parser is None:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--abc')
    return parser

def y():
    ....
    return parser

parsery = y()
parserx = x(parsery)
```

---

It might also be useful to know that `add_argument` returns a reference to the argument (Action object) that it created.

```
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
 arg1 = parser.add_argument('--abc')
```

Do this in a  shell and you'll see that `arg1` displays as:

```
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['--abc'], dest='abc', nargs=None,
     const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, 
     help=None, metavar=None)
```

`arg1` is an object that you can place in lists, dictionaries.  You could even, in theory, add it to another parser.  That's in effect what the parents mechanism does (i.e. copy action references from the parent to the child).

Answer (score -1):

You can inspire yourself from Django's [management commands](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/base.py#L116). They are basically setup as follow:

- The entry point is `run_from_argv` which calls `create_parser`, parse the command line, extract the parsed arguments and provide them to `execute`;
- The `create_parser` method creates an argparse parser and uses `add_argument` to prepopulate default options available for all commands. This function then calls the `add_arguments` method of the class which is meant to be overloaded by subclasses;
- The `execute` method is responsible to handle the various behaviours associated to the default options. It then calls `handle` which is meant to be overloaded by subclasses to handle the specific options introduced by `add_arguments`.

Your requirements are not completely clear but I think that in your case you don't need to bother with an execute method. I’d go with:

```
import argparse
import sys

class BaseParser:
    def create_parser(self, progname):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=progname)
        parser.add_argument('--temp1')
        parser.add_argument('--temp2')
        self.add_arguments(parser)
        return parser

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        pass # to be optionnally defined in subclasses

    def parse_command_line(self, argv):
        parser = create_parser(argv[0])
        options = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])
        parsed_options = vars(options)
        self.handle(**parsed_options) # HAS TO be defined in subclasses

class X(BaseParser):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--abc')

    def handle(self, **options):
        abc = options['abc']
        temp1 = options['temp1']
        temp2 = options['temp2']
        # do stuff with thoses variables

class Y(BaseParser):
    def handle(self, **options):
        temp1 = options['temp1']
        temp2 = options['temp2']
        # do stuff

x = X()
y = Y()
args = sys.argv
x.parse_command_line(args)
y.parse_command_line(args)
```

You could simplify the code further if X is a subclass of Y.